# How to test deferred action - EventMachine

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have a Sinatra app that runs inside of EventMachine. Currently, I am taking a post request of JSON data, deferring storage, and returning a 200 OK status code. The deferred task simply pushes the data to a queue and increments a stats counter. The code is similar to:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  ...

  post '/' do
    json = request.body.read

    operation = lambda do
      push_to_queue(json)
      incr_incoming_stats
    end
    callback = lambda {}

    EM.defer(operation, callback)
  end

  ...
end
```

My question is, how do I test this functionality. If I use `Rack::Test::Methods`, then I have to put in something like `sleep 1` to make sure the deferred task has completed before checking the queue and stats such that my test may look like:

```
it 'should push data to queue with valid request' do
  post('/', @json)
  sleep 1
  @redis.llen("#{@opts[:redis_prefix]}-queue").should > 0
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple and once I realized it, I felt kind of silly. I created a test-helper that contained the following:

```
module EM
  def self.defer(op, callback)
    callback.call(op.call)
  end
end
```

Then just include this into your test-files. This way the defer method will just run the operation and callback on the same thread.